# How many games can I create in Hero Academy? 

Tags: hero-academy

Is there a limit to the number of games I can create and if there is, is there a way to resign from a game or end a game prematurely?

I started a few games but it seems halfway through the opponents are not responding or playing the games.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limit to the number of games you can create is currently 40.  However, you can have more games than that active, if other players challenge you.  In other words, you can always accept challenges from other players, regardless of how many games you currently have active.

You can resign any game by clicking on the gear icon at the top of the screen and choosing the Resign menu option.  Games against random opponents auto-resign after 7 days of inactivity (with the win going to the last player who made a move).  Challenge games auto-resign after 14 days of inactivity.

I should point out that having a lot of games active, even if other players aren't currently playing, is normal.  Hero Academy is asynchronous and uses a play style popular on iOS devices, where you start a lot of games and play your turns when you have time.  It is common to go up to a day between turns, depending on the time zone and availability of your opponent.  Therefore, you should have a lot of games active, so that you have someone to play with when you want to play.